# Exscript: Telnet response includes prompt's first character?

Tags: python-3.x, telnet, telnetlib, exscript

I need to use "telnet" to connect to my camera. I had used putty and knew that the camera prompt was `'~ # '`. If I execute `'echo "test"'` then I expect the response `'echo "test"\r\ntest\r\n'`. But Exscript's response is `'echo "test"\r\ntest\r\n~'`, including the prompt's first character `'~'`.
**Code**

```
from Exscript import Host, Account
from Exscript.protocols import Telnet, SSH2
username = "root"
password = ""
host = "192.168.200.99"
account = Account(username, password)
session = Telnet(debug=1)
session.connect(host)
session.set_prompt(r"~ # ")
session.login(account)
session.execute('echo "test"')
print((repr(session.response)))
session.close(True)
```

**Code Response**

```
generic: Attempting to authenticate root.
generic: Attempting to app-authenticate root.
shell: Protocol: driver replaced: generic -> shell
shell: Protocol.app_authenticate(): driver replaced
shell: Username prompt 1 received.
shell: Shell prompt received.
shell: Calling driver.auto_authorize().
shell: Attempting to app-authorize root.
shell: Shell prompt received.
'echo "test"\r\ntest\r\n~'
```

**Putty response**

```
Network-Camera login: root
~ # echo "test"
test
~ #
```

Comment: It is better to describe your problem at the first of your question. This help you to clarify your question.